# Worksheet Change event? VBA with If and Indexing

Tags: excel, vba

I need to accomplish the following:

> 1. Capture changes in column I, where, if cell value in that column goes over a number, then index/match cell in column G and cut and paste it in the T column, starting at T13. (strictly the value of the cell only, not the formula).

I have formulas in columns G-N, which rely on the existence of a value in the G column. So once the macro gets triggered to cut the cell from column G, all rows from G-N will also delete.

Maybe this is a `worksheet_change` event, but how can it detect numerous cell changes and keep track? Also not sure about the condition and index. Below is what I have so far:

```vb
Sub Worksheet_Change()
    Option Explicit

    Dim C As Range
    Dim G As Range

    Set C = Range("I2:I615")
    Set G = Range("G2:G615")

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(C) > ("U5") Then
        rowNum = Application.WorksheetFuntion.Match(G, C, 0).CutRange("U5:U" & Range("U65536").End(xlUp).Row)
    End If

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: if this is under the Worksheet_Chage event in the Worksheet you will want to use `If Not Intersect(Target, me.place range here)) Is Nothing Then` syntax.  Hopefully that will get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: First of all, you cannot change the name of a `Worksheet_Change` event.  You can use the drop-downs in the editor to get it correct.  Secondly, `Option Explicit` goes above the subroutine.  You can read about the change event here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change

Comment: @Darrell H Right, the sub was just called Worksheet_Change, but I chose it in the drop down list. And I'll check out the Option Explicit  information

Comment: You may have chosen from the drop-down, but you edited out all the information in parentheses, which won’t work.  If you read the link, you will find that `Target` is the range that determines what changed.